# MSSP setup on PIC16F18313

Tags: microcontroller, pic, embedded, serial

I am new to using PIC16F18313 and having some difficulty setting up the MSSP module.  I am using PICKit 3 on Windows 10 with MPLAB X IDE v5.40 and XC8 compiler v2.41.

The IC has pullup resistors 4.7k on pins RA1 (SCL) and RA2 (SDA) and an LED connected to RA0 which I'm using to test program flow (it is currently blinked in ISR routine).

I am seeing no voltage changes on either SCL or SDA lines as tested with oscilloscope and can't figure out why.  There is not yet a slave device connected but I thought I should see the start sequence on the scope.

Code is following:

```
/*
 * PIC16F18313
 * Code modified from 
 * https://deepbluembedded.com/i2c-communication-protocol-tutorial-pic/
 */

// CONFIG1
#pragma config FEXTOSC = OFF    // FEXTOSC External Oscillator mode Selection bits (Oscillator not enabled)
#pragma config RSTOSC = HFINT1  // Power-up default value for COSC bits (HFINTOSC (1MHz))
#pragma config CLKOUTEN = OFF   // Clock Out Enable bit (CLKOUT function is disabled; I/O or oscillator function on OSC2)
#pragma config CSWEN = ON       // Clock Switch Enable bit (Writing to NOSC and NDIV is allowed)
#pragma config FCMEN = ON       // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor is enabled)

// CONFIG2
#pragma config MCLRE = OFF      // Master Clear Enable bit (MCLR/VPP pin function is digital input; MCLR internally disabled; Weak pull-up under control of port pin's WPU control bit.)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer Enable bits (WDT disabled; SWDTEN is ignored)
#pragma config LPBOREN = OFF    // Low-power BOR enable bit (ULPBOR disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = OFF      // Brown-out Reset Enable bits (Brown-out Reset disabled)
#pragma config BORV = LOW       // Brown-out Reset Voltage selection bit (Brown-out voltage (Vbor) set to 2.45V)
#pragma config PPS1WAY = ON     // PPSLOCK bit One-Way Set Enable bit (The PPSLOCK bit can be cleared and set only once; PPS registers remain locked after one clear/set cycle)
#pragma config STVREN = ON      // Stack Overflow/Underflow Reset Enable bit (Stack Overflow or Underflow will cause a Reset)
#pragma config DEBUG = OFF      // Debugger enable bit (Background debugger disabled)

// CONFIG3
#pragma config WRT = OFF        // User NVM self-write protection bits (Write protection off)
#pragma config LVP = OFF        // Low Voltage Programming Enable bit (HV on MCLR/VPP must be used for programming.)

// CONFIG4
#pragma config CP = OFF         // User NVM Program Memory Code Protection bit (User NVM code protection disabled)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data NVM Memory Code Protection bit (Data NVM code protection disabled)




#include <xc.h>
//#include "config.h"
#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000 // Fosc
#define I2C_BaudRate 100000 // I2C Baud Rate = 100 Kbps
#define LED LATA0 // LED is on A0


void device_setup(void) {
    OSCCON1bits.NOSC = 0b110;   // Nominal HFINTOSC = 1MHz
    OSCCON1bits.NDIV = 0b0000;  // Divider is 1
    OSCFRQbits.HFFRQ = 0b0011;  // Actual frequency = 4 MHz
    
    ADCON0bits.ADON = 0;        // Disable ADC
    CM1CON0bits.C1ON = 0;       // Disable comparator
    DACCON0bits.DAC1EN = 0;     // Disable DAC
    MDCONbits.MDEN = 0;         // Disable DSM module    
    T0CON0bits.T0EN = 0;        // Disable TMR0
    T1CONbits.TMR1ON = 0;       // Disable TMR1
    T2CONbits.TMR2ON = 0;       // Disable TMR2    
    CCP1CONbits.CCP1EN = 0;     // Disable CCP1
    CCP2CONbits.CCP2EN = 0;     // Disable CCP2    
    CWG1CON0bits.CWG1EN = 0;    // Disable CWG
    RC1STAbits.SPEN = 0;        // Disable serial port
    CLC1CONbits.LC1EN = 0;      // Disable CLC1
    CLC2CONbits.LC2EN = 0;      // Disable CLC2
    
    // Interrupts
    INTCONbits.PEIE = 1;        // Enable peripheral interrupts
    INTCONbits.GIE = 1;         // Enable global interrupts
    
    // Disable weak pullups
    WPUA = 0;
    //WPUAbits.WPUA0 = 0;
    //WPUAbits.WPUA1 = 0;
    //WPUAbits.WPUA2 = 0;
     
    TRISA0 = 0; // LED is output
    RA0PPS = 0; // LATA0 is output
    //TRISA4 = 0; // CLKOUT is output
}


void I2C_Master_Init(void) {
  SSP1CON1 = 0x28; // WCOL=off, SSPOV=off, SSPEN=on, CKP=unused, SSPM=I2Cmaster
  SSP1CON2 = 0x00; // all functions off
  SSP1STAT = 0x00; // initialise register
  SSP1ADD = ((_XTAL_FREQ/4)/I2C_BaudRate) - 1; // Baud rate
  PIE1bits.SSP1IE = 1;  // Enable MSSP interrupt
  PIE1bits.BCL1IE = 1;  // Enable MSSP bus collision interrupt
  
  
  // GPIO
  // SSP1CLKPPS = 0b00001;     // Clock on RA1
  // SSP1DATPPS = 0b00010;     // Data on RA2
  // RA1PPS = 0b11000;         // Clock output on RA1
  // RA2PPS = 0b11001;         // Data output on RA2
  
  
  TRISA1 = 1; // SCL is configured as input
  TRISA2 = 1; // SDA is configured as input
}

void I2C_Wait(void) {
  while ((SSPSTAT & 0x04) || (SSPCON2 & 0x1F));
}

void I2C_Start(void) {
  I2C_Wait();
  SSP1CON2bits.SEN = 1;  // send start bit
}

void I2C_Stop(void) {
  //---[ Initiate I2C Stop Condition Sequence ]---
  I2C_Wait();
  SSP1CON2bits.PEN = 1;  // send stop bit
}

void I2C_Restart(void) {
  //---[ Initiate I2C Restart Condition Sequence ]---
  I2C_Wait();
  SSP1CON2bits.RSEN = 1;  // send restart (in place of stop)
}

void I2C_ACK(void) {
  //---[ Send ACK - For Master Receiver Mode ]---
  I2C_Wait();
  SSP1CON2bits.ACKDT = 0; // 0 -> ACK, 1 -> NACK
  SSP1CON2bits.ACKEN = 1; // Send ACK Signal
}

void I2C_NACK(void) {
  //---[ Send NACK - For Master Receiver Mode ]---
  I2C_Wait();
  SSP1CON2bits.ACKDT = 1; // 1 -> NACK, 0 -> ACK
  SSP1CON2bits.ACKEN = 1; // Send NACK Signal!
}

unsigned char I2C_Write(unsigned char Data) {
  //---[ Send Byte, Return The ACK/NACK ]---
  I2C_Wait();
  SSP1BUF = Data;
  I2C_Wait();
  // LATA0 = ~LATA0;
  return ACKSTAT;
}

void __interrupt() ISR(void) {
  if (PIR1bits.SSP1IF) {  
      PIR1bits.SSP1IF = 0; // Clear The Interrupt Flag
  }
  if (PIR1bits.BCL1IF) {
      PIR1bits.BCL1IF = 0; // Clear the interrupt flag
  }
  LATA0 = 1;
  __delay_ms(20);
  LATA0 = 0;
}


void main() {
    
  unsigned char i=1;
  device_setup();
  I2C_Master_Init();
  while(1)
  {
    I2C_Start(); // I2C Start Sequence
    I2C_Write(0x40); // I2C Slave Device Address + Write
    I2C_Write(i++); // The Data To Be Sent
    I2C_Stop(); // I2C Stop Sequence
    __delay_ms(500);
    //LATA0 = ~LATA0; // Toggle LED Each Time A Byte Is Sent!
  }
}
```

Comment: Looking at the code, why are SDA and SCL configured as inputs? If there's no slave device, there's no input.

Comment: To the best of my understanding from 30.6 in datasheet: "In Master mode, the SDA and SCK pins must be configured as inputs. The MSSP peripheral hardware will override the output driver TRIS controls when necessary to drive the pins low."  (Note I wonder whether the reference to SCK is a typo in the datasheet as the rest of the I2C documentation refers to SCL as the clock line).  The datasheet I have is revison F 09/2019.

Comment: Are the PPS selections under GPIO commented out when you compile your code? Note 2 under PIC16(L)F18313 PINOUT DESCRIPTION says that "All pin outputs default to PORT latch data. Any pin can be selected as a digital peripheral output with the PPS output
selection registers. See Register 12-2." So even though they are the default I2C pins, they don't default to the MSSP peripheral.

Comment: Also remember that to change the PPS (peripheral pin select) selections, you will need to unlock the PPS to make changes. The PICkit 3 should allow debugging, so you can check the various PPS registers are what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

On PIC16F8313 all pins with the capability of analogue functionality default to analogue.  Therefore to enable digital operation the appropriate bit in the ANSELA register must be cleared.